# Installing Yeoman errors

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am new to Ubuntu and to Angular. I am attempting to set up a Yeoman framework. However each time I run the "yo" command. the following errors occur:

```
 Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/diarmuid/tmp/npm-2997-20XPEB7W'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/diarmuid/tmp/npm-2997-20XPEB7W']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/diarmuid/tmp/npm-2997-20XPEB7W',
npm ERR!   parent: 'davidmoshertutorial' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/diarmuid/AngularTutorial/DavidMosherTutorial
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path /home/diarmuid/tmp/npm-2997-20XPEB7W
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
```

Does anyone understand how to solve this? I tried to run "sudo yo" however I got response to :

```
change to change where npm stores global packages by
putting ~/npm/bin in your PATH and running:
npm config set prefix ~/npm
```

I ran to gedit ~/.profile and edited the file to this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/~/npm/bin"
fi
```

I am obviously a bit lost. If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run this command:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/tmp
```

the `tmp` folder within the home directory should be owned by the user, not by the admin.

Comment: +1 Worked great.  Just curious but can anyone explain why if this folder should be owned by the user it was owned by root on my (and obviously many others) machine (OSX)?

Comment: @DarrenLewis it happens when you run npm (on local projects) with root permissions (sudo), than it creates files and folders which are owned by root.